# How can I access a local file over the web?

Tags: filepath

How can I get this to work correctly?  I want to access a file form the Z drive on my local machine using this code. How should I put the file path?

embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="VLC" autoplay="yes"
loop="no" volume="100" width="640" height="480" target="z:/familymovies/babysteps.flv"

Comment: Not familiar with that plugin, but you could try: `file:///z:/familymovies/babysteps.flv`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a webserver? You need to have one, then you need to put your file in the folder hierarchy that the server serves.

Unless you don't really mean "over the web". If you're on the same machine, use the file: protocol as the other answer says.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just access it that way. One solution would be to run a webserver on your local machine, expose it using something like DynDNS, then access the file via that path.